# Laravel: how to save blob image to storage with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a image blob url like this : blob:http://127.0.0.1:5500/d97212fe-8f01-4486-8840-36acc57f77bc , how i can store it to storage image with Laravel

Answer (score 1):

It simply means you want to get the contents of a remote image file and save it in your Laravel application's storage folder. You can use `file_get_contents` for that.

The complete code will be:
Import storage Facade on the top of your file:

```
use Storage;
```

Code in the Controller function or anywhere you may want to use it:

```
$url = "http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$name = time().'.png';
Storage::put($name, $contents);
```

It's simple dummy code, you will have to add logic to create a filename.

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storing-image-file-retrieved-from-external-url?page=1